# Mark specific tag helper element name as Obsolete

Tags: c#, .net-core, tag-helpers

I know you can use the `[Obsolete]` attribute to mark classes and methods as obsolete/deprecated, but can the same be done for specific tag names for a tag helper? For example, I am looking into adding a prefix to all of the tag helpers in our in-house CMS, but would like to phase out the original ones slowly. So `<page-toolbar>` would instead become `<cms:page-toolbar>`. I tried putting the `Obsolete` inside of the same brackets as the `HtmlTargetElement`, like this:

```
namespace Cms.TagHelpers
    [HtmlTargetElement("page-toolbar"), Obsolete("The <page-toolbar> tag is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0. Use <cms:page-toolbar> instead.")]
    [HtmlTargetElement("cms:page-toolbar")]
    public class PageToolbarTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public PageToolbarTagHelper() { }

        //...
    }
}
```

However, that just made the whole method obsolete as expected. As a workaround, I created a class that inherits the tag helper class and deprecated *that*. But is there an official/better way to handle this?

```
namespace Cms.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("cms:page-toolbar")]
    public class PageToolbarTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public PageToolbarTagHelper() { }

        //...
    }

    [Obsolete("The <page-toolbar> tag is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0. Use <cms:page-toolbar> instead.")]
    [HtmlTargetElement("page-toolbar")]
    public class PageToolbarDeprecator : PageToolbarTagHelper
    {
        public PageToolbarDeprecator() { }
    }
}
```